# Websocket Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

Tags: php, websocket

I have written a chat server using `php and Ratchet` as my websocket framework.
On localhost the connection works very well and the chat also works well

I uploade my project on `github` and hosted it on `openshift v3`. I have run the `pod` with my socket server and its running smoothlly.

The probem is that i cant connect my client application to the websocket server and i keep getting this error:

```
controllers.js:742 WebSocket connection to 'ws://172.30.153.75:8000/?user_id=20&chat_id=35' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response
```

I know that openshift uses port 8000 for  non secure websockets and that is what i have used. The IP am using is the ip of the service where my chat-server

When i try to inspect in chrome this are the headers i have

General

```
Request URL:ws://172.30.153.75:8000/?user_id=20&chat_id=35
```

Request Headers

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Upgrade
Host:172.30.153.75:8000
Origin:http://localhost:8100
Pragma:no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key:c/1ullN6H0Bt9JH8tHQs5Q==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2965.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
```

querystring parameters

```
user_id:20
chat_id:35
```

What could be the problem? can anyone help me?

Comment: and no response (response headers) at all?

Comment: No response at all